# How can I include unit tests in maven assembly?

Tags: maven-2, assemblies, junit, include

Reason: Our project is using Ant as commandline interface. After making a new assembly with maven's assembly plugin, I want to make initial tests to see if all has been properly assembled. Therefore I need to include the unit tests in the final assembly. After assembling, the initial tests would then be called sth like

```
> ant initTest
```

build.xml:

```
<target="initTest">
  <junit>
   <test class="MyTest" />
  </junit>
</target>
```

Problem is: 
I want to keep my Unit tests in src/test/java and *not* move them to src/main/java.
Is there a way to tell the assembly plugin to include my unit tests? A simple *include* in the assembly descriptor does not do it ...

Answer (score 10):

There are two steps:

1. Package the tests into a jar as well as the main code.
2. Depend on that "-tests" jar in the module that makes the assembly.

To package up the tests, you need to bin the [jar:test-jar](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/test-jar-mojo.html) goal.  e.g.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>test-jar</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>test-jar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Then in the assembly module, you can depend on the resulting artifact.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupid>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <classifier>tests</classifier>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The key bit is the "classifier".

Comment: the dependency should probably also have the scope "test"

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @Dominic-Mitchell did not work for me at all. What finally worked was adding a `fileSet` for the test classes to my assembly xml. **Note that the fileSet directories are different!** That stumped me for the longest time.

Use `${project.build.directory}` for the test classes and `${project.build.outputDirectory}` for the main:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<assembly>
    <id>toolbar-test</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>

    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>

    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <unpackOptions>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/LICENSE*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/README*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </unpackOptions>
        </dependencySet>
        <dependencySet>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Credit where credit is due - I found this solution within this blog post here: http://alexgaddie.blogspot.com/2010/02/creating-uber-jar-with-maven.html 
I did not need the `profile` part of the blog post.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for us.

`pom.xml` snippet:

```
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>           
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`assembly.xml` snippet:

```
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>/lib</outputDirectory>
        <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
        <useProjectAttachments>true</useProjectAttachments>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

The key is the `useProjectAttachments` tag.